# Relationship between Perceptrol algorithm and MLP (Multiplayer perceptrol neutral network)

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition, perceptron

recently I started learning pattern recognition and I'm very interested in Perceptron algorithm. But sometimes I heard other students talking about Perceptron network, that is a type of neutral networks. What is the relation ship between them?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should review your terminology first.
It's MULTILAYER, PERCEPTRON, NEURAL network.

That aside, wikipedia is always your friend: [MLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron)

At the highest level, you can think of a MLP as a network of perceptron units (although I'm probably oversimplifying it).

Comment: Thanks, I know it is MLP. But Is there any relation between Perceptron algorithm (Supervised learning) and MLP? (same word Perceptron)

Comment: If you mean if both can be used for supervised learning, yes you're right.

Comment: The perceptron learning algorithm lets you change the weights of a perceptron unit in order to learn (approximate as good as possible the target function you're searching for). I'm assuming you know what a perceptron unit is and how it works (it takes the weighted sum of its inputs etc...). Are you familiar with these concepts?

Comment: Yes, I just learned it. So u mean that perception learning algorithm is for training neuron network (identify weight vector)?

Comment: Exactly. There are many more algorithms to find such vector, one of which is the MLP. It uses a network of neurons that perform different activation functions than the perceptron neuron. A perceptron neuron uses the linear threshold function, while in MLP you can have different layers of neurons that can use different activation functions like the sigmoid.